# Tricky SQL SELECT problem (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, hierarchical-data

Having this table (sorry, cant seem to get a decent layout here):

```
PD      Header         Text              Mask_Producer      Mask_Dep        Mask_Diam
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10      Producer       Aproducer         Aprod              *               *
10      Producer       Bproducer         Bprod              *               *
20      Diam           A                 Aprod              10              30
20      Diam           A                 Aprod              20              40
20      Diam           B                 Aprod              10              40
30      Dep            10                Aprod              10              *
30      Dep            20                Aprod              20              *
30      Dep            30                Aprod              30              *
20      Diam           A                 Bprod              20              40
30      Dep            10                Bprod              10              *
```

I am using the rows in the table as a filter/mask for selecting other rows.

So, user having already made a selection of rows with:

```
PD   Text
-------------
10   Aproducer
20   A
```

I would now like to find out what rows with PD=30 fits those previous choices:

PD=10, Text=Aproducer gives that Mask_Producer must be "Aprod", (Mask_Dep and Mask_Diam are allowed to be anything by the stars)

PD=20, Text=A gives that Mask_Producer must be "Aprod" and Mask_Dep must be 10 or 20 and Mask_Diam must be 30 or 40 (or star)

I want the outcome to be rows 6 and 7 from the table above.

Then imagine this example with 2000rows and 20 Mask_xx fields....

I am thinking SQL like IN, LEFT JOIN, JOIN, and temporary tables to do this, but I think I may be complicating things too much....

Comment: make the data code, (4 spaces) so it at least renders in monospace.

Comment: Thanks for not using tabs - the markdown syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I don't understand what the rules are that you are attempting to capture in your query.  For example, why should rows 6 and 7 be the desired output?  I don't see the pattern.

Comment: Looks like the schema needs to be redesigned. What do the columns (other than Mask_*) signify?

Comment: It is a system of interelated data for choosing in step by step pulldown menus. Hard to explain the idea fully as its kind of complicated. Will try to clearify tomorrow. Thanks for help with formatting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the type of code I enede up using, it works, but as I add more criteria and fields I get more huge joins and in each join also more AND..OR...OR sequences, so any propositions for improvements are welcome! Especially I am consernde that this may be slow as data grovs? Analysis of what the sql sever has to do for my code is welcome too!

Right now I have about 30 criteria/fields and some PHP code that generates the SQL query for me....

But here is the smaller example for the principle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t30.*
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE PD = 10
     AND Text = 'Aproducer') AS t10
JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE PD = 20 AND Text = 'A') AS t20 ON 
     (t20.MaskProducer = t10.MaskProducer
                                OR t20.MaskProducer = '*'
                                OR t10.MaskProducer = '*')
     AND (t20.MaskDep = t10.MaskDep
                                OR t20.MaskDep = '*'
                                OR t10.MaskDep = '*')
     AND(t20.MaskDiam = t10.MaskDiam
                                OR t20.MaskDiam = '*'
                                OR t10.MaskDiam = '*')
//more JOINS like the one above for each criteria
// below the final join to get the result from
JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE PD = 30) AS t30 ON 
       (t30.MaskProducer = t20.MaskProducer
                             OR t30.MaskProducer = '*'
                             OR t20.MaskProducer = '*')
        AND (t30.MaskDep = t20.MaskDep
                             OR t30.MaskDep = '*'
                             OR t20.MaskDep = '*')
        AND (t30.MaskDiam = t20.MaskDiam
                             OR t30.MaskDiam = '*'
                             OR t20.MaskDiam = '*');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are asking for but I am more familiar with SQL Server so if my syntax is off a little please forgive me.  You should be able to do an inner join, joining the table to itself to get the results you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbData A
JOIN tbData B ON A.PD = B.Mask_Dep AND A.Mask_Producer=B.Mask_Producer
WHERE A.PD = 10
    AND A.Text='Aproducer'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM tbData A
JOIN tbData B ON A.PD = B.Mask_Dep AND A.Mask_Producer=B.Mask_Producer
WHERE A.PD = 20
    AND A.Text='A'
```

Looking at this I think I am a bit off but some of your data isn't clear.  Could you give more universal rules for what you are looking for in the Mask_Dep and Mask_Diam?

Comment: Hi, you could be on to something, but A.PD = B.Mask_Dep is clearly not right, these fields are not related....

Comment: Point taken. It seems like the rules for A.PD and B.PD are different.  Is that the case?  If not could you give me a unified rule?  I think if you can then I could probably help you.

Comment: Got this solved from another source (rob_farley):

SELECT t30.* FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE PD = 10 AND Text = 'Aproducer') as t10 JOIN ( SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE PD = 20 AND Text = 'A') as t20 ON (t20.MaskProducer = t10.MaskProducer OR t20.MaskProducer = '*' OR t10.MaskProducer = '*') AND (t20.MaskDep = t10.MaskDep OR t20.MaskDep = '*' OR t10.MaskDep = '*') AND(t20.MaskDiam = t10.MaskDiam OR t20.MaskDiam = '*' OR t10.MaskDiam = '*') 

...continued in next comment....

Comment: JOIN ( SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE PD = 30) as t30 ON (t30.MaskProducer = t20.MaskProducer OR t30.MaskProducer = '*' OR t20.MaskProducer = '*') AND (t30.MaskDep = t20.MaskDep OR t30.MaskDep = '*' OR t20.MaskDep = '*') AND (t30.MaskDiam = t20.MaskDiam OR t30.MaskDiam = '*' OR t20.MaskDiam = '*');

This works it seems, and can be expanded to more mask fields/criteria, but will generate a huge query when used with 20 mask fields or so, so if anyone has a better solution, please comment! Each criteria generates one more join, and each mask field generates one more AND (...)

Comment: Petter, post your solution as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.  It will make it easier for people in the future to find and it will stop anyone from looking at it as your problem is solved!

Comment: I agree, update the question at least with the new data that excludes my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT r.* FROM table AS c -- choices
JOIN table AS r            -- results
    ON (
        (r.mas_dep = '*' OR c.mask_dep = r.mask_dep)
        AND
        (r.mask_diam = '*' OR c.mask_diam = r.mask_diam)
    )
WHERE (
    ( c.pd = 10 AND c.text = 'Aproducer' )
    OR ( c.pd = 20 AND c.text = 'A' )
)
AND r.PD = 30
```

This will take the result of the choices:

```
PD      Header         Text         Mask_Producer   Mask_Dep    Mask_Diam
10      Producer       Aproducer    Aprod           *           *
20      Diam              A         Aprod           10          30
20      Diam              A         Aprod           20          40
```

And self-join it against the master table, where these conditions hold true `r.mas_dep = '*' OR c.mask_dep = r.mask_dep` and `r.mask_diam = '*' OR c.mask_diam = r.mask_diam`. This will return a set of:

```
PD      Header         Text         Mask_Producer   Mask_Dep    Mask_Diam
30      Dep              10         Aprod           10          *
30      Dep              20         Aprod           20          *
```

It will exclude the others clearly because their mask_deps of 30 isn't in the choice resultset, and it will exclude the rows pds not 30.

Comment: This looks like you undestand me! Will think and try and let you know. Thanks for now, gotta sleep...;-)

Comment: Hi, Evan, now tested, almost works! ....if I add these rows #9: "20  Diam A Bprod 20 40" and #10: "30 Dep 10 Bprod 10 *" I will get #9 in the choices (wrong) and then also #10 included in the result (wrong)....any suggestions?